# Why do I need the Season Ticket for loading a Career Mode save state?

Tags: xbox-360, fifa-12

I've experienced this now for the third time since I bought the game:

[image: Season pass requirement on career mode load]

Every time I want to continue any Career Mode game this screen appears. It's in German, but it's telling that my Career Mode save contains leagues to which I've no access anymore. They suggest that I have to buy the Season Ticket or buy content in the FIFA store.

I'm able to play the Career Mode from the beginning. This happens on the first load of the save state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

The solution is to delete the "UGC Data 1" entry on the storage device. I also had problems with the roster update, which led me to:

http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/1166419.page

Obviously, "UGC Data 1" is some corrupted Creation Center data, which became obsolete with an update month ago. Unfortunately, they were not automatically deleted.

It is possible now to load, continue my career and to download roster updates. Hope that helps somebody else.

Answer (score 3):

You're [not](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111101134417AAaR25g) [the](http://www.gamespot.com/fifa-soccer-12/forum/need-season-ticket-for-career-mode-60474231) [only](http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/1198248.page) [one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/631377-fifa-soccer-12/60474547?page=1) who's had this happen, but there isn't much out there to explain why this is happening. You might confirm that you didn't somehow start Career Mode with a team that was downloaded from the Creation Centre. One of the things that you get with Season Ticket is [below](http://www.easports.com/seasonticket):

> Career Mode Pack
>
> - Entitles you to use - and actually play with - downloaded Creation Centre teams in Career Mode by swapping teams during New Career setup.
> - Entitles you to use a downloaded Creation Centre tournament (league type only) in Career Mode by selecting the league during New Career setup.

If you're using standard leagues, as most of those other people were, then I would guess it is just a bug that, sadly, doesn't seem to have a fix yet.

Comment: I've deleted all of my Creation Center content ingame. So i thought, this would solve all the problems on the Creation Center front. According to my solution, this was not enough.

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis By deleting the UGC file on the ps3, will you be able to load the career save with a creation centre team? It's just that I bought the "Career mode pack" and worked fine for a few days, but now I cannot load my career save with my created team but can load my other career with a standard team save, for example my other save as AFC Wimbledon. By deleting the UGC file, does it delete all of your creations and does it affect the fact you have bought the "Career mode pack"? Thanks

Comment: @Thomas, unfortunately I don't know. I'm not familiar with the contents of the files that FIFA 12 creates; [Matthias' answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47171/8366) is the one that mentions deleting those UGC files, and that post on EA's forums does not mention what else would be contained in those files.